# On the validity of int *a={1,2,3}. Why does a subsequent *a crash?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
int main()
{
   int *a={1,2,3}; //which value is stored and where it is stored 
   printf("\n%d",*a); //crashes here
}
```

Please explain why the above is crashing.

Comment: You should have got a compiler warning about excessive initializers list.

Comment: `error: scalar object 'a' requires one element in initializer`

Comment: Ya I got warnings ,but still I can able to execute

Comment: Yes, often you can execute programs with undefined behavior, but who knows what they will do.... One lesson: take all warnings seriously and fix them.

Comment: Perhaps it is converting the first value `1` to a pointer.

Comment: An initializer list is different from a string literal.

Comment: Because there is no "array address" here. The initializer does not have any.

Comment: @lurker -- what array? `{ 1, 2, 3 }` is an initializer list.

Comment: @DavidBowling sorry, bad terminology on my part. I meant array in a generic sense. I was making vague reference to the fact that if it were `int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 }` C takes the initializer list and builds the array from it and you'd have an array of 1, 2, and 3. I've deleted my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: are you sure it passed compilation process? I

Comment: @lurker -- in that case the array would be on the left, initialized by the initializer list. Since C99 you could do `int *a = (int []) { 1, 2, 3 };` using a _compound literal_.

Comment: @DavidBowling Hm. Is this literal statically allocated? I remember reading something about it in the standard, but I don't recall..

Comment: @vamshi.: what is the answer? I am curious to know.

Comment: @DavidBowling yes, I understand. I deleted my initial comment to avoid the confusion with my generic use of the word "array".

Comment: If u do print("%d",x); it will take first value as address ,de reference will cause crash because it is not a valid memory

Comment: Well, if you think it is the *answer*, then I expect to see you here again...

Comment: @EugeneSh. -- ["If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p5)

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks, that's it.

Comment: Looks like one of you dudes should answer this. I will upvote it.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posted code has undefined behavior, so it may compile and execute, but the results are unpredictable. One possible outcome is a segmentation fault.

The line:

```
int *a={1,2,3};
```

attempts to initialize a pointer to `int` with an *initializer list* (which contains too many elements; this should generate a warning), but this initializer list is *not* an array.

One solution would be to use an actual array:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int *a = arr;
```

Here `arr[]` is an incomplete array type. The initializer list is used to initialize the array `arr[]`, and when the end of the initializer list is reached, the array type is completed. Now `a` is a pointer to the first element of the array `arr[]`, which has type `int [3]`.

Another option, available since C99, is to use a *compound literal*:

```
int *a = (int []) { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Here, the compound literal creates an anonymous array, and `a` points to the first element of this array. Note that this anonymous array would have *automatic storage duration* in the case of the posted code, which is to say that it is exists only while program execution is within the `main()` block. In general, according to [§6.5.2.5 5 of the C11 Draft Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p5):

> If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block.

Comment: One tiny note: As I learned, `int *a={1,2,3};` is a constraint violation and should give an _error_ instead of _warning_ by a conforming compiler.

Comment: @machine_1 -- the Standard only says that an implementation must issue a _diagnostic_ for constraint violations. This may be a warning or an error, but the Standard makes no distinction; that is implementation-specific.

Comment: @vamshi.: Don't change the selection of answer after you have done it once...it's really strange and awkward for both the person. (Give proper thought before you do it first time - frequently changing is not a good thing in many of the person's opinion).

Comment: @coderredoc -- I appreciate the support, but OP should accept whichever answer is most helpful to them :)

Comment: @lurker.: You said *fickle* ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all from standard

```
       initializer:
                   assignment-expression
                   { initializer-list }
                   { initializer-list , }
```

So you are using initializer list.

From standard [6.7.9p11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11)

> The initializer for a *scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces*. The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

So that's it. `int *a={1,2,3}` is not legal code.

But even if you try something like this

```
int *a = {1};
```

Compiler will comlain about  `error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]`.

You can do this though,(But there is not much you can do with this)

```
int *a = {(int*)1};
```

But dereferencing this may lead to undefined behavior. (i.e.,segmentation fault).

Answer (score 2):

`int *a={1,2,3};` here `a` is a pointer, It's expecting some **valid address** ,It's the programmer job is to assign some valid address to it so that it couldn't point to random address.

Although it's *undefined behaviour* but here `a` is initialized with first element. so its looks like

```
 int *a = 1;
```

when you are doing `*a`, it crashes because you are trying to de-reference **invalid address**.

Solution is first allocate memory dynamically and then do the operation as

```
int *a = malloc( 3 * sizeof(int));
        a[0]= 1;
        a[1]= 2;
        a[2]= 3;

        for(int i = 0 ;i< 3 ;i++) {
                printf("\n[%d]\n",a[i]);
        }
```

Once job is done free the memory to avoid memory leakage as

```
free(a);
```

**Note :** An initializer list `{ }` is different from a string literal `" "`.

```
int *a = {1}; /* a didn't get any address */
int *a = "1"; /* a gets address*/
```